Is there a way to undock browser developer tools using a script or a registry entry?
I'm looking for a script or registry modification to automatically undock the browser developer tools and open them in the background.
I've tried using the shortcut (Press F12, then Cmd + Shift + D, and Cmd + Shift + P to select undock), which works but requires doing it manually the first time. After that, pressing F12 remembers the last position.
I want to eliminate the second step of pressing Cmd + Shift + D Or Cmd + Shift + P to select undock.
Any help would be appreciated!

It may be possible to configure devtools via selenium-chromedriver similarly to this example for puppeteer.
